# Shown JTable from Database with calculate formula

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing, jtable

I want to shown a JTable with Value from database, but in some coloumn that calculate with a formulation. for excample like this :
Table in database :

[image]

from that table i want to shown in JTable, with calculation :
 coloumn Pendidikan and Skripsi, value is direct from database.
 column Penelitian and MK, value from database calculate with formula value in row minus average from that coloumn. the result shown in table:

[image]

so, how  to make it like that?, but the formula building in java

Comment: What code do you have that attempts this?  When you parse through the result set you can just do your calculation and add all the data to your JTable

Comment: sory, i am noobs in programer. i don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: Do you have any code that attempts to solve your problem?

Comment: I'd read the JTable tutorial (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and pay careful attention to the bit about creating a custom table model

Comment: @Dan, please read my code  in answer below.

Answer (score 0):

this my code to show data to JTable:

```
 tabModel = new DefaultTableModel(null,header);
        tabel.setModel(tabModel);  
try { String query = "SELECT NIP,Pendidikan,Penelitian,MK,Skripsi FROM table1 group by NIP";
java.sql.Statement Stat = Connect.createStatement();
java.sql.ResultSet rs = Stat.executeQuery(query);
while (rs.next()) {
   String nip = rs.getString("NIP");
   String bidang = rs.getString("Bidang");
   String pendidikan = rs.getString("Pendidikan");
    String penelitian = rs.getString("Penelitian");
   String mk = rs.getString("MK");
   String skripsi = rs.getString("Skripsi"); 
String[] dataTampil = {nip,bidang,pendidikan,penelitian,mk,skripsi};
tabModel.addRow(dataTampil); 
tabel.setModel(tabModel);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){}
}
```

but, i can't calculate the table with differnt formula for every coloumn.
for coloumn Pendidikan and skripsi the value direct from database, but for coloumn Penelitian and MK the value form Value in Row minus Average for thats coloumn.

Comment: Please include the code with your question, not as an answer to it

Answer (score 0):

You should first be using rs.getInt() since as your sample shows in your original question, that they are in fact integers.  Once you have them as Integers you can do whatever calculations you need to for  Penelitian and MK instead of using the ones from the database.  In other words, for these two variables, set them to whatever calculation they should be instead of just using the value from rs.getInt()